# How to get JSON Response of List Format

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

I am getting a Jason response of this format.

```
[
    {
        "total": "5",
        "tracking_id": 780,
        "type": "Unplanned",
        "severity": "High",
        "NOTIFICATION_TYPE": "FINAL",
        "Service": "M2MMC-Notification",
        "location": "Billerica",
        "state": "MA",
        "lat_dec": "42.5663890000",
        "long_dec": "-71.3236110000",
        "Maintenance_Performed": "",
        "Work_Performed": ""
    },
    {
        "total": "5",
        "tracking_id": 581,
        "type": "Unplanned",
        "severity": "High",
        "NOTIFICATION_TYPE": "FINAL",
        "Service": "M2MMC-Notification",
        "location": "Billerica",
        "state": "MA",
        "lat_dec": "42.5663890000",
        "long_dec": "-71.3236110000",
        "Maintenance_Performed": "",
        "Work_Performed": ""
    },
    {
        "total": "5",
        "tracking_id": 598,
        "type": "Planned",
        "severity": "LOW",
        "NOTIFICATION_TYPE": "SUBMITTED",
        "Service": "M2MMC-Notification",
        "location": "Billerica",
        "state": "MA",
        "lat_dec": "42.5663890000",
        "long_dec": "-71.3236110000",
        "Maintenance_Performed": "BREAKFIXAPPLICATION",
        "Work_Performed": "VOLTE"
    },
    {
        "total": "5",
        "tracking_id": 791,
        "type": "Unplanned",
        "severity": "High",
        "NOTIFICATION_TYPE": "FINAL",
        "Service": "M2MMC-Notification",
        "location": "Billerica",
        "state": "MA",
        "lat_dec": "42.5663890000",
        "long_dec": "-71.3236110000",
        "Maintenance_Performed": "",
        "Work_Performed": ""
    },
    {
        "total": "5",
        "tracking_id": 795,
        "type": "Planned",
        "severity": "LOW",
        "NOTIFICATION_TYPE": "CANCELLED",
        "Service": "M2MMC-Notification",
        "location": "Nationwide",
        "state": "",
        "lat_dec": "0",
        "long_dec": "0",
        "Maintenance_Performed": "BREAKFIXAPPLICATION",
        "Work_Performed": "VOLTE"
    }
]
```

Can any one please help me in how to get this format in my Serenity with Java code.

Comment: Hi, I see you are new to Stack Overflow - Welcome to the community. It is a good idea to try and search for your answer online (google, etc.) and if you do not find any answer, please describe what you looked for already.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you shared what you tried so far, but anyways here goes.

Assuming you're using some kind of object mapper (i.e Jackson could be a potential candidate), you'll first need a pojo class mapping the body of your request.

In your case this would look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Pojo {

    private String total;
    public String getTotal() { return total; }
    public void setTotal(String total) { this.total = total; }

    @JsonProperty("tracking_id")
    private Integer trackingId;
    public Integer getTrackingId() { return trackingId; }
    public void setTrackingId(Integer trackingId) { this.trackingId = trackingId; }

    private String type;
    public String getType() { return type; }
    public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }

    private String severity;
    public String getSeverity() { return severity; }
    public void setSeverity(String severity) { this.severity = severity; }

    @JsonProperty("NOTIFICATION_TYPE")
    private String notificationType;
    public String getNotificationType() { return notificationType; }
    public void setNotificationType(String notificationType) { this.notificationType = notificationType; }

    @JsonProperty("Service")
    private String service;
    public String getService() { return service; }
    public void setService(String service) { this.service = service; }

    private String location;
    public String getLocation() { return location; }
    public void setLocation(String location) { this.location = location; }

    private String state;
    public String getState() { return state; }
    public void setState(String state) { this.state = state; }

    @JsonProperty("lat_dec")
    private Double latDec;
    public Double getLatDec() { return latDec; }
    public void setLatDec(Double latDec) { this.latDec = latDec; }

    @JsonProperty("long_dec")
    private Double longDec;
    public Double getLongDec() { return longDec; }
    public void setLongDec(Double longDec) { this.longDec = longDec; }

    @JsonProperty("Maintenance_Performed")
    private String maintenancePerformed;
    public String getMaintancePerformed() { return maintenancePerformed; }
    public void setMaintancePerformed(String maintancePerformed) { this.maintenancePerformed = maintancePerformed; }

    @JsonProperty("Work_Performed")
    private String workPerformed;
    public String getMaintenancePerformed() { return maintenancePerformed; }
    public void setMaintenancePerformed(String maintenancePerformed) { this.maintenancePerformed = maintenancePerformed; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo{" +
            "total='" + total + '\'' +
            ", trackingId=" + trackingId +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", severity='" + severity + '\'' +
            ", notificationType='" + notificationType + '\'' +
            ", service='" + service + '\'' +
            ", location='" + location + '\'' +
            ", state='" + state + '\'' +
            ", latDec=" + latDec +
            ", longDec=" + longDec +
            ", maintenancePerformed='" + maintenancePerformed + '\'' +
            ", workPerformed='" + workPerformed + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

}
```

With this in hand reading the list of objects is quite easy and boils down to this:

```
 public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        List<Pojo> pojoList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_BODY, new TypeReference<>() {});
        pojoList.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps!